# Is there a way to quickly reduce precision in a number of DOUBLE fields?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, database, dynamic

I was wondering if there is a way to reduce the precision for display of a DOUBLE field of a number of fields, in a shapefile. I have 25 fields and would like to do it as automatically as possible but I'm not certain where to start. I don't particularly want to create new fields and transfer over the values manually. I am displaying the text using dynamic text on data driven pages . I just want to display it with two rather than 5-6 decimal places.

This is what the attribute table looks like, along with the relevant portion of layout:

[image]

Here is the field properties box:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure these data are in a shapefile?  Shapefiles don't have fields of type double: they store all numbers as ASCII strings with fixed width and fixed number of decimal places.  Also, why do you make a reference to the Field Calculator?  The rest of the question seems to have nothing to do with that.

Comment: I assumed that it was possible to do that with field calculator. Is that not the case? It is a shapefile. I created all of the fields myself with a python script and chose them as DOUBLE. I will append another screenshot edit: I removed the reference to field calc in the question

Comment: If you just hit the number icon in that printscreen you posted Emily, do you not have the ability to reduce the number of decimal placed right in there?

Comment: Ahh, yes, that is what I was looking for. Is there a way to do this quickly for all 25 fields?

Comment: Ok - I'm going to post this as an answer to make up for my BAD ANSWER then.  Sorry I didn't read more carefully Emily

Comment: @Dano is right. click the ellipses next to numeric and change the decimals

Comment: @Brad, do you know of a way to do this quickly?

Comment: Re your first comment:  ArcGIS does its best to make sense of what you ask.  When you request a double field for a shapefile, you're going to get a numeric field with a default width and default decimal places.  So it worked, but maybe not exactly as you had intended.  This is one of many technical reasons why we make distinctions among shapefiles, geodatabases, and other sources of GIS data, and--unfortunately--one of many examples of why you need to be aware of some of the engineering details behind the uniform interface presented by ArcGIS.

Comment: @whuber Is there somewhere that I can find more information about these details? I know it isn't relevant to this question, but as I can't PM or email you, I'm writing a comment.

Comment: ESRI publishes white papers on their file formats and other technical aspects of all things Arc*.  Look for them on their pages.  Reading GIS.stackexchange regularly will attune you to many of these issues, too :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of ways to accomplish these types of tasks.
1. Round ([myfield], 2)  This works for field calculator, labeling, etc.
2. in the layer dialog left click the  label column and select format labels
3. select the number format in the field properties and change the number of decimals.

[image: screen1]
[image: Screen2]

Answer (score 3):

**CORRECTION TO BAD ANSWER:**

Just hit the circled tab in my printscreen.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to do this without creating new fields.

Answer (score 0):

I used the arcpy.Calculatefield_managment option in  ARCPY to achieve the same result

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
Workspace = 'N:\\FGDB.gdb\\'

Feature = 'Featureclass'

In_Feature = Workspace + Feature
Field_round = 'Length_KM'
Round_operator = 'round(!Length_KM!,2)'
print Round_operator
arcpy.CalculateField_management(In_Feature, Field_round, Round_operator ,'PYTHON', '')
```

Comment: I recognise this is an old question but I thought a better solution was available